# What is the advantage of IntStream over usual Stream?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

How is `IntStream`, `DoubleStream`, or `LongStream` better than regular stream in Java 8?

Do these threads have high performance or maybe usability?

Comment: I find them convenient. They have some operations that are special for numbers. I would expect that they also perform a bit better, not something I know.

Comment: @OleV.V. What operations?

Comment: @AntonSorokin e.g. [`IntStream#summaryStatistics()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#summaryStatistics())

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Stream<Integer>` etc. have to work with boxed values (`Integer` instead of primitive `int`) which takes significantly more memory and usually a lot of boxing/unboxing operations (depending on your code). Why only `Int/Double/Long`? Just because they were expected to be used most often.

Same applies to `OptionalInt` and friends and all the functional interfaces.

For collections (lists/maps/sets) there are many third-party libraries providing primitive specialization for the same reason. Really the problem there is even more acute because with streams you don't (usually; `sorted()` is a counter-example) need to store many values in memory.

Comment: "with streams you don't  need to store many values in memory" But what about parallel streams? Isn't their advantage in handling large amounts of data?

Comment: Two comments: first, on `IntStream` and alike, you have [`summaryStatistics()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#summaryStatistics()), which gives you easy access to statistical information like min, max, mean,.... Second, [project valhalla](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/valhalla/) aims to neglect the problem with additional object creation, although I am not convinced that this is a huge memory/performance problem overall.

Comment: @Turing85 True, but in a world where Java already had generics over primitives when `Stream`s were added, I'd be _very_ surprised if `IntStream` was a separate type instead of making `Streams.summaryStatistics(Stream<int>)`. As it is, `IntStream` provides a convenient place to put it.

Comment: @AntonSorokin Still as streams, so they don't need all elements in memory.