# What is the difference between IntStream and Stream<Integer>?

Tags: java

Trying to wrap my head around the difference between `IntStream` and `Stream<Integer>`. I illustrate with an example below:

```
int[] someInts = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
var intStream = Arrays.stream(someInts);
var streamInteger = Arrays.stream(someInts).boxed();
```

What is the difference between both? And how does the difference relate to performance?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the advantage of IntStream over usual Stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54840920/what-is-the-advantage-of-intstream-over-usual-stream)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> What is the difference between both?

[`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) is a stream of *primitive* `int` values.

[`Stream<Integer>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) is a stream of `Integer` *objects*.

The list of operations available are different, just check the list of methods in the javadoc. E.g. `IntStream` has built-in concepts of [`range(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range(int,int)) and [`sum()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sum()), not that `sum()` is difficult to do with `Stream<Integer>` using `reduce()`, but it isn't built in.

> How does the difference relate to performance?

Boxing and unboxing does take some time, but it's not a lots. A lot of temporary boxed objects also triggers Garbage Collection a lot more often, and that's a performance drain too. It all adds up, so if the stream processes a lot of integer values in a tight "loop", the difference can be relevant.

The bigger problem is space, since the overhead of `Integer` is quite large. An `int` is 4 bytes for the value, while an `Integer` is 4 bytes for the reference plus 16 bytes for the object, so `Integer` uses 20 bytes per value, i.e. 5 times the memory.

This is especially relevant if you call `toArray()`, since there's a big difference between an `int[]` and an `Integer[]`, space-wise.

Answer (score 2):

`Stream<Integer>` operates on boxed values (`Integer` instead of primitive int) which takes significantly more memory and usually a lot of boxing/unboxing operations (depending on your code), whereas `IntStream` works with primitives.