# Why doesn't IntStream.spliterator() return Spliterator.OfInt since Java 11?

Tags: java, java-stream, java-11, boxing

In Java 8, [`IntStream.spliterator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#spliterator--) is overridden from the base class to return type `Spliterator.OfInt`, which is a sub-interface providing methods that operate on an `IntConsumer` instead of a generic `Consumer<Integer>`.

But since Java 11 (and continuing with 17 and 20), [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) inherits the base class `spliterator()` method which only returns a generic `Spliterator<Integer>`.

I believe the reason for these specialized primitive types is largely to avoid the expensive overhead of constant boxing and unboxing (see for example [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54840979/1008966)). If so, then there is a performance hit for using `Spliterator<Integer>` rather than `Spliterator.OfInt`. Does anyone know why this specialization in `IntStream` was removed?

Comment: The [OpenJDK repository on GitHub](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/stream/IntStream.java#L879) suggests that it still returns `Spliterator.OfInt`.  Have you actually failed to compile code that expects `Spliterator.OfInt`, or just looked at the Javadoc?

Comment: Interesting that JavaDocs say `spliterator` is inherited. That certainly isn't true on my copy of JDK 17.

Comment: @LouisWasserman well now I feel like up is down and black is white. How could there be such a discrepancy - isn't the javadoc generated from this source? (I also checked on [devdocs.io](https://devdocs.io/openjdk~11/java.base/java/util/stream/intstream) and same thing there.)

Comment: Yes, but it seems that the Javadoc generated from the JDK doesn't include overridden methods in detail if they don't have their own Javadoc comment (which you can see `IntStream#spliterator()` does not from the source code link provided by Louis). It shows them in sections like "methods declared in <parent>". I'm not sure why this is the case; I'm not an expert in the `javadoc` tool, but I can't seem to reproduce the behavior shown by the standard library's documentation.

Comment: If you don't provide explicit Javadoc for an overridden method it just generates the basic information inherited from the parent method.

Comment: Side effect of [JDK-8157000](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8157000). The issue has been noticed already, see [JDK-8219147](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8219147) but it seems it didn’t cover all cases. Maybe, generics complicated matters. See also [JDK-8296607](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8296607).

Comment: Re _"the expensive overhead of constant boxing and unboxing"_ and the _"performance hit"_, you might want to look at this [recent and authoritative SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73336364/2985643). In particular, note from the final paragraph of that answer: _"...even if boxing happens, does it really matter? How many billion-billion boxing operations would it take for this to show up on your performance metrics?"_

Comment: Holger's comment finally let me reproduce the problem. Looks like the JDK generates its documentation with `--override-methods=summary`. That means an overridden method that does not provide its own Javadoc comment, nor changes the return type, will not be documented in detail. That makes sense. But it appears there's a bug, and the tool seems to have missed the fact that the discussed `spliterator()` method had its return type changed from `Spliterator<T>` to `Spliterator.OfInt`. I wouldn't be surprised if this bug was simply the order they perform checks, as [cont.]

Comment: [cont.] a `Spliterator.OfInt` is a `Spliterator<Integer>`. That change is already documented in the class documentation, as `IntStream` is a `BaseStream<Integer, ...>`. So, why document it again in the method? But that ignores that `Spliterator.OfInt` is a covariant return type, thus the bug.